# Net SSH Perl error trying to use exit code

Tags: perl, ssh

**CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSH::Perl;

my $ssh_to="10.1.1.9";
my @KEYFILE = ("/home/nagios/.ssh/id_dsa.pub");
my $local="10.1.1.5";
my $vip_ip="10.1.1.50:80";

my $remove  = "/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/ipvsadm -e -t $vip_ip -r $local -w 0";
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($ssh_to, identity_files=>\@KEYFILE);
my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($remove);
if ( $exit eq 0) { sleep(300); }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[root@host]# ./mytest.pl

Use of uninitialized value in string eq at ./mytest.pl line 14, <GEN0> line 1
```

Comment: Please post the code you actually ran, or show the output of the code you actually posted.

Comment: the goal of the if statement is to sleep for 5 minutes if exit 0 if not then die

Comment: this is the actual code I ran

Comment: To be clear, this error is occurring at the `if` statement?

Comment: yes, I cannot figure out how to trap for exit 0

Comment: I've seen in other examples that the `if` statement is written as `if ($exit eq '0')` (with quotes around the zero).  Have you tried this?

Comment: PS - If you're comparing numbers, you should be using `==`. That's not going to make `$exit` become defined, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In perl, eq is for strings, == is for numbers, just an FYI!

You are getting the error, because $exit is not defined.

Try this test:

```
if ( defined( $exit) && ( $exit== 0 ) ) {
    sleep( 300 );
}
```

This will ignore non-errors ( $exit is undef ) and will sleep when there is an $exit = 0

Now, why are you trying to trap exit 0 and why are you sleeping when it happens?

Comment: Isn't exit defined in the previous line my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit)?When we run the remote command we want to sleep for 5 minutes before we continue our code, if the remote command fails (exit status code other then 0 then we want to die

Comment: You are 100% correct, I mistyped $exit as $error, should be fixed soon.  Even though the script is giving you the error right now, are you able to confirm the command is running on the server correctly?

Comment: now the it just exit's so that tells me that the exit code was not a 0 which is proven by the fact that my command isn't executed on the remote host